# Private Reply with Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I made a bot where it can monitor the comment and find out which one is the newest comment and that work great.
I tried to add a feature where i can send a private_replies to the user that made the comment, i check all the doc and search on the internet but am still confusing as how should i do it ?

```
def monitor_comment():
    print("Bot is monitoring comments")
    #Getting the data from fb
    comment_data = graph.get_connections(COMBINED_POST_ID_TO_MONITOR,"comments",order='reverse_chronological')
    commends = []
    for comment in comment_data['data'][:10]:
        commends.append (comment)
    #Configure it so that i can take the first line of 'id'
    data = commends[0]['id']
    #Convert data to string cuz it doesn't work for some reason
    data_converted = str(data)
    return data_converted
#This is where it private_reply to the commend_id from above
def private_reply(comment_id):
    #AM CONFUSE HERE
    private_reply = graph.put_object(comment_id,"conversations",  message= "Hello This is a test")
    return private_reply
```

Comment: Why, what part of what the documentation explains are you having trouble with?

Comment: Private_Replies section, It just that i dont know how to configure it so that whenever there is a new comment the bot will send a private_replies to them.

Comment: But you said you _had_ the part to have the bot "monitor" for new comments already? So where is the problem then - your "monitor" recognizes that there was a new comment made, so go and reply at that point then ...?

Comment: Yes, But the thing that i want to do is to PRIVATE_REPLIES to the user that just comment. [Private_Replies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/private-replies)

Comment: I dont know if it graph.put_object(comment_id,"private_replies",  message= "Hello This is a test") or other thing. That's the part where am confuse about.

Comment: The _endpoint_ you need to send this to, is `/me/messages`. Everything else, needs to be supplied as parameters for that request.

Comment: So in terms of [`put_object`](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#put-object), that would mean `parent_object='me', connection_name='messages', /* rest of parameters */`

Comment: Ok so now it facebook.GraphAPIError: (#100) The parameter recipient is required           This is what i wrote private_reply = graph.put_object(parent_object='me',connection_name='messages',recipient_comment_id=data_conserve, message="Test")

Comment: You need to send an element/object called `recipient`, and inside that there has to be a property `comment_id`. (Don't ask me how that translates into whatever specific syntax the Python SDK might require, I don't know.)

Comment: I done that but it now said facebook.GraphAPIError: (#100) param recipient must be non-empty. This is the code graph.put_object(parent_object='me',connection_name='messages',recipient = comment_id, message="Test"). The commend_id is the comment_id of function monitor_comment and it return in Str. @CBroe

Comment: No, you did not. You provided the comment ID as value for recipient directly. You need to match the format the example request in the documentation shows. The JSON portion they are sending there, is `"recipient": { "post_id": "542998526103632_461184817813069" }` - that is the format that you need to match (with `comment_id` instead of `post_id` of course.) What you are currently sending, would be the equivalent of just `"recipient": "542998526103632_461184817813069"`

Comment: Ohhhh so that why, but how do i put comment_id in the element recipient. Thanks you so much for helping me all this time

Comment: graph.put_object( parent_object='me',connection_name='messages', recipient='null',comment_id=comment_id, message="Test") This is the best i can figure it out but it still fail.

Comment: I can't tell you what syntax this SDK would require for this. But I guess that touches on Python basics rather than Graph API to begin with.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.